# Weblogic application on a cluster behavior

Tags: java, weblogic11g

I have an application that successfully deploys to Weblogic Server. I've configured cluster and wanted to start this application on a cluster, but sometimes I am facing such a situation.
1st node - application runs and there isn't any errors.
2st node - shows me 404 error.

How is that possible that 1 application can successfully work on 1 node and show 404 error on the second one?

Comment: Is the application targeted to both nodes?

Comment: yes, when I deploy the application I am selecting the whole cluster.

Comment: How are you accessing the page that gives you a 404? Have you tried hitting each managed server directly using *hostname:port/applciation* ?

Comment: first node, which works: http://localhost:7004/APPNAME
second node, which gives me 404: http://localhost:7005/APPNAME

servers are in cluster and have running state. I've checked the ports - they are also correct.
Even on Deployments menu my APPNAME is Active.

Comment: Try this. Stop the second one, in the servers folder in domain home, remove the tmp, stage and cache folders and start the server back up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer and thanks to @Kyouma.
The problem was in JMS server.
I had such a configuration:
1 Machine that has 2 servers united in a cluster.
JMS Server that was targeted to 1 server from the cluster.
JMS Module that was targeted to the same server.
The problem was, that I had *.war file configured to both servers in a cluster.
When the first server was starting - everything was fine, because during Topic bean creation he could find those topics. But the second server couldn't find them, because JMS server in general was not in Running state.

So the solution is:
1. Have no *.war files in the Deployment menu.
2. Start all servers in a cluster.
3. Install *.war file in the Deployment menu.
E.R. Application have been deployed.